# Dsharp GetAllMembersAsync() psermison needed

Tags: dsharp+

I am trying to get all the members of a guild. When i use `GetAllMembersAsync()` i get an exception of unauthorized 403. I tried to give the bot all permissions but I am still getting the exception.

Minimum reproducible example of code that may return this issue

```cs
private static async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<DiscordMember>> 
  GetEveryone(DiscordClient client, DiscordGuild guild)
{
    DiscordGuild myGuild = await client.GetGuildAsync(guild);
    var members = myGuild.GetAllMembersAsync();
    return members;
}
```

Thx for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the question was asked but I wanted to answer for anyone who comes here in the future.

When creating your client you must declare your intentions with `DiscordConfiguration()` and not just by giving the bot permission in Discord's developer portal. To be clear, both your bot and Discord's developer portal must have matching configurations to avoid an HTTP 403 or 401 error. In the main method for creating your discord client you likely have something like this set up:

```cs
    var discord = new DiscordClient(new DiscordConfiguration()
    {
        Token = tokenHere,
        TokenType = TokenType.Bot
    });
```

To declare this intention you must set the `Intents` configuration as well:

```cs
    var discord = new DiscordClient(new DiscordConfiguration()
    {
        Token = tokenHere,
        TokenType = TokenType.Bot,
        Intents = DiscordIntents.All
    });
```

The minimum `Intent` for your purpose is `DiscordIntents.GuildMembers`, however, there are many `Intents` and you can declare them individually. Be sure to [check out the examples from DSharp+](https://dsharpplus.github.io/articles/beyond_basics/intents.html).

Important: `Server Member` intents are a part of the Privileged Gateway Intents set. You must set the `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` configuration in the Discord Developer Portal Bot tab to true to act upon any Discord members in any way. Not all bots will have this access immediately but generally, most developers will be able to declare this intent after a short time.